# Spring Cloud - Config Client slows down metric /health

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am using the ConfigServer within my Spring Boot + Spring Cloud project. I used to monitor the endpoint /health, but since the ConfigClient asks the ConfigServer within every request, the invocation of the metric "/health" is quite slow.

This is due to the fact, that for every request to the ConfigServer, this one actually calls BitBucket –> so the entire request chain is quite long/slow.

Is there a way to disable the check for ConfigServer being available? I would like to monitor this one separately.

Best
fri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently.  How often are you checking health? You can submit an issue to have a property that disables the health check.

You could work around it by extending `ConfigServerHealthIndicator` and overriding `doHealthCheck`.

The do something like:

```
@Bean
public ConfigServerHealthIndicator configServerHealthIndicator(
        ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator locator) {
    return new MyEmptyConfigServerHealthIndicator(locator);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I will create a feature request for that.

Comment: Added a feature request here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/159

Comment: Sorry for replying to such an old answer, but for the record the property has been added (and I believe also - renamed) in the meantime. Setting `management.health.config.enabled: false` disables the behaviour described in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve issue need to do below changes in Client application:

Need to change dependency in build.gradle file

compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:1.0.4.RELEASE")

Add below piece of code in bootstrap.yml for Client Application

health:
  config:
    enabled: false